# How to create one grid from specific set of points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, grids-graticules, point

I need to create one grid/fishnet from a set of points (coordinates). I tried to do it with the point to path tool following this three steps:

1-Vertical's rows: I numbered the points in the vertical of 1 to 8
       and created one vector with point to path tool.
2-Horizontal's rows: I numbered the points in the horizontal with odd
       numbers and created another vector with point to path tool.
3-Following, I merge this vectors.

However in the end result, I noticed that the lines created were parallel. 
[image]
The lines pass in the points one more time. I tried separated the parallelal lines with vector --> data management tools --> split vector layer. I tried also vector--> geoprocessing tools --> dissolve. But both did not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. You may wish to [edit] your question to include additional detail about how your results differed from your first attempt to subsequent attempts. Also, please include how, exactly, you "separat[ed] the lines."

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated way of making a fishnet.  Is there a special reason why you are not using the "create Grid" tool?  The only reason you'd not use this tool is if your grid is not regular (though it looks like it is).

Comment: Yes, my grid is not regular because the points cover a big area in the world and tereby my area deform at the extremes (I need use UTM projection!). I used "create grid" tool but my points  showed up displaced in relation the grid created from this tool (even I putting both vectors in the same EPSG). I tried to fix it activating "snapping" tool and moving the grid with edition tool of layer. After I did it, some points were right, but anothers displaced about of 15 meters.